# Instantiating the self class inside a method?

Tags: php, class, oop

Is there any problem if I am instantiating the current class inside its method ? I am using this code:

```
Class Say_Hi (){

    function __construct(){
        echo "Hi";
    }

    public function again( $data ){
        new Say_Hi();
    }

}
```

Comment: The ol Jurassic Park axiom rings true here: "Yeah, yeah, but your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could that they didn't stop to think if they should." Basically yes you can, but it is not good practice.

Comment: One common use case for this is factory methods attached on the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can certainly do this and it will work correctly.